# regex google app script: insert $ for absolute reference in row only

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

trying to turn long formulas into absolute row reference using GAS, here is a short example.

looking turn this:
`=IFERROR((AW220-AW221)/(AW216*4)/1000+AW217)`

into this:
`=IFERROR((AW$220-AW$221)/(AW$216*4)/1000+AW$217)`

I need all cell references to be anchored by row.

I can strip it out `formula.replace(/\$/g,"")`, not sure how to put it back in. i can only match using `[A-Z]+[0-9]+`, now what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      =IFERROR((AW220-AW221)/(AW216*4)/1000+AW217)
    ```
  - To

    ```
      =IFERROR((AW$220-AW$221)/(AW$216*4)/1000+AW$217)
    ```

I thought that in this case, when the formulas are retrieved as R1C1, the script might be able to be simple. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set your expected range as A1Notation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const rangeA1Notation = "'Sheet1'!A1:C10"; // Please set your range as A1Notation.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const range = ss.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  const values = range.getValues();
  const newValues = range.getFormulasR1C1().map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => c ? c.replace(/R\[(.*?)\]C\[(.*?)\]/g, (_, p2, p3) => `R${Number(p2) + i + 1}C[${Number(p3)}]`) : values[i][j]));
  range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the script searches the formulas. And, the ranges of each formula are modified like `AW220` to `AW$220`.
- When I tested your formula of `=IFERROR((AW220-AW221)/(AW216*4)/1000+AW217)`, this script converts it to `=IFERROR((AW$220-AW$221)/(AW$216*4)/1000+AW$217)`.

#### Note:

- As additional information. I thought that this method might be useful for other users. So, I published the enhanced script of the above script to https://medium.com/google-cloud/converting-relative-reference-to-absolute-reference-and-vice-versa-of-a1notation-on-google-f9a908bde904. In this script, the relative reference can be converted to the absolute reference and vice versa of the a1Notation in formulas. And, 3 absolute reference patterns can be used.

```js
/**
 * ### Description
 * This is a sample script for converting the relative reference to the absolute reference and vice versa of A1Notation using Google Apps Script.
 *
 * Author: Tanaike ( https://tanaikech.github.io/ )
 */
class ConvertReference {
  /**
   * ### Description
   * Constructor of this class.
   *
   * @param {string} a1Notation Please set a range as a1Notation. It's like "'Sheet1'!B3:E5".
   * @return {void}
   */
  constructor(a1Notation) {
    this.a1Notation = a1Notation;
  }

  /**
   * ### Description
   * Convert the absolute references to the relative references.
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  absoluteToRelative() {
    const { range, offsetR, offsetC, values, newR1C1Values } = this.getValuesAndOffset_();
    const regex = [new RegExp("R([-,0-9].*?)C([-,0-9].*?)", "g"), new RegExp("R\\[([-,0-9].*?)\\]C([-,0-9].*?)", "g"), new RegExp("R([-,0-9].*?)C\\[([-,0-9].*?)\\]", "g")];
    const newValues = newR1C1Values.map((r, i) =>
      r.map((c, j) => {
        const check = regex.findIndex(e => e.test(c));
        if (check != -1) {
          return c.replace(regex[check], (_, p2, p3) => {
            if (check == 0) {
              return `R[${Number(p2) - (i + offsetR)}]C[${Number(p3) - (j + offsetC)}]`;
            } else if (check == 1) {
              return `R[${Number(p2)}]C[${Number(p3) - (j + offsetC)}]`;
            } else if (check == 2) {
              return `R[${Number(p2) - (i + offsetR)}]C[${Number(p3)}]`;
            }
          });
        }
        return c[0] == "=" ? c : values[i][j][0];
      })
    );
    range.setValues(newValues);
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * ### Description
   * Convert the relative references to the absolute references.
   *
   * @param {number} conversionPattern Pattern for converting. 1: (=A1 --> =$A$1) 2: (=A1 --> =$A1) 3: (=A1 --> =A$1)
   * @return {void}
   */
  relativeToAbsolute(conversionPattern) {
    const { range, offsetR, offsetC, values, newR1C1Values } = this.getValuesAndOffset_();
    const newValues = newR1C1Values.map((r, i) =>
      r.map((c, j) => c ? c.replace(/R\[(.*?)\]C\[(.*?)\]/g, (_, p2, p3) => {
        let f = "";
        if (conversionPattern == 1) {
          f = `R${Number(p2) + i + offsetR}C${Number(p3) + j + offsetC}`;
        } else if (conversionPattern == 2) {
          f = `R[${Number(p2)}]C${Number(p3) + j + offsetC}`;
        } else if (conversionPattern == 3) {
          f = `R${Number(p2) + i + offsetR}C[${Number(p3)}]`;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Invalid value.");
        }
        return f;
      }) : values[i][j])
    );
    range.setValues(newValues);
    return null;
  }

  getValuesAndOffset_() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.a1Notation);
    const range = sheet ? sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()) : ss.getRange(this.a1Notation);
    const offsetR = range.getRow();
    const offsetC = range.getColumn();
    const values = range.getValues();
    const newR1C1Values = range.getFormulasR1C1();
    return { range, offsetR, offsetC, values, newR1C1Values };
  }
}

// Convert the relative references to the absolute references.
function sample1() {
  const a1Notation = "'Sheet1'!B3:E5";
  const conversionPattern = 1;

  new ConvertReference(a1Notation).relativeToAbsolute(conversionPattern);
}

// Convert the absolute references to the relative references.
function sample2() {
  const a1Notation = "'Sheet1'!B3:E5";

  new ConvertReference(a1Notation).absoluteToRelative();
}
```

#### References:

- [getFormulasR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)